# when it say "Built-in battery", then does it mean that "battery is not user-replacable"?

Tags: battery

Read this line in iPhone 2G specification http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_2G

```
Built-in rechargeable Li-ion battery 3.7 V 1400 mAh
```

So, "Built-in battery" means "battery is not user-replacable"?

Is that true?

Or, "built-in" means "hard-welded" (ie fixed forever)
& "not user-replacable" means "user can replace if using special tool but Apple does not encourage user to do that"

Comment: by "not user-replaceable" do you mean "not-user-replaceable without extraordinary effort"? http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+1st+Generation+Battery+Replacement/448

Comment: yes, "not user-replacable" means  "user can replace if using special tool but Apple does not recommend"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean the original iPhone, and the 2G is referring to the antenna capabilities, rather than the 2nd Generation iPhone (which was the 3G.... yeah, confusing)?

Either way, all iPhones have a built in battery.  The wording is there to suggest that it is not user replaceable via a simple swap in/out method by removing a panel or similar user appropriate action that does not require disassembly.  The iPhone 5 still uses broadly similar language "*[Built-in rechargeable lithium-ion battery](http://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/specs/)*".

You can swap it out, but it's not a simple job.  Just like cars have a built in engine, you can get that sucker out, but you need the tools, parts and skills for the job.  If I recall, there is a lot og glue involved in earlier iPhone models.  And sticky tape.  It's not just a case of unscrewing some stuff and swapping.  But even then, the glue can be removed, the tape replaced etc etc.  The phrasing *user-replaceable* or more commonly *user-serviceable* often means it's a supported solution, and there is no way that taking any iPhone to bits is covered under warranty.

So, in short, built in means it's not *meant* to be removed, but that doesn't mean you cannot do it if you tried hard enough.

Comment: iphone 2G = iphone 1st generation; iPhone 3G=iPhone 2nd generation

Comment: so "built-in" does not mean "hard-welded" forever? it mean if the battery got malfunctioned then we have to throw away the phone? in iPhone 3G they say "not user-replaceable", they did not say "built-in"

Comment: The original battery is has its contacts soldered, then covered in glue, and further more it is stuck to the internals with adhesive tape.  That's pretty built in.  But clearly, you *can* remove it and replace it, if you have the skills. Later phones used more friendly clamp based connections without the glue and solder, but were still taped in and still required full disassembly of almost every part of the phone to get to them.  Marginally easier in total, removing the skill with a soldering iron required, but still what I would call built in.  Non user-replaceable is just a cover term.

Comment: so, "built-in" is harder to take it out than "not user-replaceable". In the "not user-replaceable", there is no glue & adhesive tape, but in "built-in" case it has glue & adhesive tape & thus it harder to take it out.

Comment: In this instance, but those terms really are just interchangeable stuff for *You are not allowed to mes with this if you want your warranty intact*  The wording may have flip flopped over time; even a battery that is user replaceable via a removable cover is *built in*, maybe they changed the wording to make it clearer.

Comment: ok, thax you very much